# php-extension php7-mod-* not load in OpenWrt

Tags: php-extension, openwrt, php-openssl

I got `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function openssl_decrypt()` message in my lighttpd using php file.

I already have `php7-mod-openssl`, but `php-cli -m` not showing openssl.

- OpenWrt version: 21.02
- php version: 7.4
- lighttpd version: 1.4.61

Here are my config and package:

1. `php7-mod-openssl`:

```
# opkg list |grep php
php7 - 7.4.24-1
php7-cgi - 7.4.24-1
php7-cli - 7.4.24-1
php7-fastcgi - 7.4.24-1
php7-fpm - 7.4.24-1
php7-mod-openssl - 7.4.24-1
```

2. `php-cli -m`:

```
# php-cli -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
hash
pcre
posix
Reflection
SPL
standard
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

3. `extension=openssl.so`:

```
#php-cli --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php7
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php7/15_openssl.ini
```

```
# cat /etc/php7/15_openssl.ini 
extension=openssl.so
```

4. `openssl.so`:

```
# cat /etc/php.ini |grep extension
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php"
```

```
# ls /usr/lib/php/
openssl.so
```

Am I missing something?
any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

[update] change title from php7-mod-openssl to php7-mod-*.

I have installed other php7-mod like phar, ftp, curl etc.
but `php-cli -m` not show anything, also config is same with openssl like above.

Looks like there is some reason cause mod can not load.

Comment: lighttpd provides mod_openssl for lighttpd.  If you are using lighttpd in front of PHP, then you should configure lighttpd mod_openssl.  https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_SSL   I believe that the PHP openssl.so is for use when PHP *client* makes TLS connections to another host.  The latest lighttpd 1.4.69 is available in openwrt 21.03.  Please consider upgrading your openwrt.  `opkg -h`

Comment: Hi @gstrauss, thank you for your response. However, I am experiencing an issue with the `openssl_decrypt()` function, which is provided by the php7-mod-openssl extension. It seems that the mod_openssl module does not directly affect the `openssl_decrypt()` function in PHP.

Comment: Yes, `openssl_decrypt() is provided by php7-mod-openssl.  If you are using PHP to do TLS encryption and decryption: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php and if you are using lighttpd to do TLS encryption and decryption:  https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_SSL  If you are using PHP behind lighttpd, you should almost always be configuring lighttpd to do TLS encryption and decryption, and a PHP backend -- running on the local machine and listening on a filesystem-protected unix domain socket -- does not need to (and can not) additionally use TLS when communicating with lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

Add define `HAVE_LIBDL` and `-ldl` to EXTRA_LIBS in configure.ac file to fix php-extension can not load issue